# Cypress Finding element by partial element name

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I would like to get this element in cypress tests but using only part of string without 'undefined'. How can I do that?

```html
<line-chart-undefined tabindex="0"></line-chart-undefined>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily done with XPath.

1. Install [cypress-xpath](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath) plugin

```sh
  npm i -D cypress-xpath
```

2. Then include in your project's `cypress/support/index.js`

```js
  require('cypress-xpath')
```

3. After installation your `cy` object will have `xpath` command

```js
  cy.xpath("//*[starts-with(name(), 'line-chart-')]")
```

It'll find the element that matches the `line-chart-` tag

Answer (score 4):

Since `cypress-xpath` is now deprecated, this is how you would do it with CSS selectors

```js
cy.get('parent-element')
  .children()
  .filter((index, element) => element.tagName.startsWith('line-chart'))
```